# Proper/easy way of calling methods from a program on remote server in java?

Tags: java, network-programming

The project we are doing requires using some private data, such as usernames and passwords to use apis, databases etc.

As end user should not know these, I guess the right way to do this is,

1. End user program doesn't know any passwords. It just makes call to program on remote server
2. The program on remote server knows the passwords, it executes the stuff and returns reply to end user program
3. End user program displays the result

I wonder if the right and/or easy way to do this is end user program sending packets over an UDP/TCP connection, with information regarding method to call and the arguments. Then server program reports back using same method. Is there a better/easier way to do this in Java?(i.e some library/classes?)

Comment: I think this type of question suites [programmers.se] better. Read their "how to ask" and try there.

Comment: Your question may be off topic. See [http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use spring boot https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ to develop a restful api.
I have an example here using spring boot and mongodb that you can check out https://github.com/RbkGh/Restful-BulkSMS